Why volume of cone is not $ \frac{\pi r^2 h}{2}$
One of the proofs I used to know in my childhood is that volume of cone be  $ \frac{\pi r^2 h}{2}$ . Like , take a normal cylinder and slice off its smallest plate. Why do we slice it off? A cylinder is formed by the rotation of a plate (rectangle). Now, let's cut the diagonal of that plate.
Since the plate ABCD is a parallelogram, cutting the diagonal will make two corresponding triangles for the sake of equality; let those be $ABC$ and $ADC$.
Now, rotating these two triangles in the same manner by which we rotate the cylinder will make two cones. Notice the radius of the cone is equal to the base formed by rotating $ABC$ and $ADC$, exactly equal to the width of plate $ABCD$, and their length will be equal to the opposite side (diagonal), that is, $AB$ and $AD$.
So, by this, we can easily conclude that cones formed by $ADC$ and $ABC$ have the same radius as the original cylinder. Since there are only two such cones, we can now argue that:
$$ \text{Volume of Cylinder} = 2 \times \text{Volume of Cone} $$
$$ \frac{\text{Cylinder}}{2} = \text{Volume of Cone} $$
$$ \frac{\pi r^2 h}{2} = \text{Volume of Cone} $$
My question doesn't contradict the proof we have about cones; my question is about where I went wrong in my proof.

What do you mean by "slice off its smallest plate?"

If you consider that diagonal as the axis and rotate your "plate", or rather the largest rectangular cross section of the cylinder, will you get a cylinder?

Have you seen the disk and shell methods? I think the geometry of your perspective, handled correctly, ends up with a shell method.

Yeah, "smallest plate" is meaningless.

By smallest plate I mean the plate with the least thickness like chopping up a cylinder

"Plate" is the meaningless word, @skyecrane

If I followed your explanation correctly, the error is in the assumption that by rotating triangles ABC and ADC you get two cones. What is actually obtained is one cone and one solid which is a complement of the cone with respect to the cylinder. There is little to no basis for the claim that these objects have the same volume. Correct volumes can be obtained in a standard way, using calculus, for example.

For the cone, the best way to prove the volume of a cone is to take advantage of rotational solids.
Note the general formula for the disc method about the x-axis for some function $f$ such that $x\in[a,b]$:
$$V=\pi\int_a^bf^2(x)\;dx$$
Consider the line extending from the origin to some arbitrary point $r$ units above the x-axis and $h$ units to the right of the y-axis.
This line has the following formula and domain:
$$f(x)=\frac{r}{h}\cdot x$$
$$x\in[0,h]$$
Consider the solid of revolution formed by rotating this line about the x-axis. Replacing our variables:
$$V(r,h)=\pi\int_0^h\left[\frac{r}{h}\cdot x\right]^2\;dx$$
Squaring the integrand and extracting constants:
$$V(r,h)=\pi\cdot\frac{r^2}{h^2}\int_0^hx^2\;dx$$
Integrating:
$$V(r,h)=\frac{\pi r^2}{h^2}\cdot\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_0^h$$
Applying bounds:
$$V(r,h)=\frac{\pi r^2}{h^2}\cdot\frac{h^3}{3}$$
Simplifying:
$$V(r,h)=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$

This isn't the question being asked, however. The question is a. "What's wrong with this proof?" question.

@Thomas is right. I want to know the actual place where I went wrong.

Put the cone in the cylinder so that the half of the plate you retain sweeps through the same volume as it did in the cylinder (before the cut).  At one end, the disk common to both the cylinder and the cone are swept out by the same edge of the retained triangle.  At the other end, the disk is missing from the cone and (in the cylinder) is swept out by the edge that was removed.
This might lead us to suspect that the amount missing from one disk cross-section anywhere is equal to the amount present in the cross-sectional disk the same distance from the other end of the cylinder.
Let's check that in the middle.  In the middle, the entire area of the disk (in the cylinder) is $\pi r^2$ and the part that is kept after cutting the plane in half has half the radius, so the cone has area $\pi (r/2)^2 = \pi r^2/4$ on this disk.  This is not half the area of the cylinders disk, it's one-quarter.
So let's do this generically for any circular cross-section.  We get a paint brush of width $w$ and paint the small disk in the center with a disk of radius $w$, then we paint the stripe of points of distance $\leq w$ from the edge.  Note that there is way more paint in that stripe than in that little disk in the middle.  That is, among the cone's two disks the same distance from the ends of the cylinder do not add up to the cross section of the cylinder, except at the very ends.  Everywhere else, the cone has less than half the area, so the cone has less then half the volume of the cylinder.
We can imagine leaving the two cut pieces of the plate where they are and use each to sweep out congruent cones, by revolving them around edges that were opposite on the plate.  These two cones would give the volume of a cylinder if the volume of a cylinder were twice that of its inscribed cone.  In each cross section parallel to the ends (except for the midpoint, which we addressed above), there is a smaller disk (of radius $w$) and a larger disk (of radius $r-w$).  As we discussed above, the smaller disk does not have enough area to go all the way around the larger disk.  That is
\begin{align*}
\pi(r-w)^2 + \pi w^2 
    &= \pi (r^2 - 2rw + w^2) + \pi w^2 \\
    &= \pi (r^2 - 2rw + 2 w^2) \\
    &= \pi r^2 - 2\pi w(r - w)
\end{align*}
We see the $\pi r^2$ for the area of the clyinder, but we have to take away some area.  The amount taken away is zero when $w = 0$ or $w = r$, at the ends.  Between the ends, $w > 0$ and $r-w > 0$ so we remove some positive area.  We have found that every cross section perpendicular to the cones' axes has too little area for the cylinder.  Two copies of the same cone do not have the volume of the circumscribing cylinder.
